Pebble Template calculate the line coverage in a template
I'm using Pebble templates for my data transformation use cases (not web pages rendering).
I receive data in json, I produce a json out using pebble templates.
There are many scenarios in my templates that I exercise in my unit tests.
Is there any way in pebble templates I can hook into every expression that gets evaluated and capture the line number and produce a coverage report?
I'm thinking of instrumenting a pebble template much the same way the code coverage tools work and show which lines in the templates are covered and which arent?
